# Python: Build Graphs with set of sets adjacency list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, graph, set

Hello this is my first post and I'm not fluent in English, so forgive me if I do any wrong post protocol ....

so, I have this current implementation of a graph, through an adjacency matrix:

```
class GFG: 
def __init__(self,graph): 
    self.graph = graph
```

from which I start like this:

```
my_shape = (N,M)
bpGraph = np.zeros(my_shape)
```

and add edges like this:

```
vertex_a = 2
vertex_b = 5
bpGraph [vertex_a, vertex_b] = 1
g = GFG(bpGraph)
```

and check for an edge like this:

```
if bpGraph [vertice_a, vertice_b]:
do something...
```

But this type of structure can take a lot of space if I have a lot of vertices, so I would like to switch to a set map

```
class GFG: 
def __init__(self,N,M):
    mysetdict = {
        "dummy_a": {"dummy_b","dummy_c"},
    }
    self.graph = mysetdict 

def add_edges(self,N,M):
    N_set = {}
    if str(N) in self.graph:
        N_set = self.graph[str(N)]
    N_set.add(str(M))

    self.graph[str(N)] = N_set

def check_edges(self,N,M):
     return str(M) in self.graph[str(N)]
```

When I try to add a vertex I get this error:

```
g = GFG (3,4)
g.add_edges (0, 0)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'
---> 16                 N_set.add(str(M))
```

im trying many ways to build this set and check if a entry exists before add a vertex_a to do a edge with vertex_b, but all my tryes results in a atribute error.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

solved, just doing N_set = set()

```
def add_edges(self,N,M):
    N_set = set()
    if str(N) in self.m_graph:
        N_set = self.m_graph[str(N)]
    N_set.add(str(M))

    self.m_graph[str(N)] = N_set
```